# загрузить ту переменную которая не пустая в переменную?

Tags: php

загрузить ту переменную которая существует и не пустая в переменную c помощью тернарного оператора

```
$token = $_COOKIE['token'] ? $_GET['token']
```

Comment: чаво???????????

Comment: я вот так это делаю `function coalesce() {
  foreach(func_get_args() as $item) {
   if (! empty($item)) return $item;
  }
  return '';
 }`

Comment: видимо так, но код страшен isset($_COOKIE['token']) ? $_COOKIE['token'] : isset($_GET['token']) ? $_GET['token'] : null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используете php7+ то лучше так, а не тернарным оператором:

```
 $token = $_COOKIE['token'] ?? $_GET['token'] ?? null;
```

Comment: `??` - а это не тернарный оператор??

Comment: @Alpha, это оператор `null coalescing`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$token = isset($_COOKIE['token']) ? $_COOKIE['token'] : $_GET['token'];
```